# Xamarin Android Release Build Error

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

we are developing an business application using Xamarin Android. 
We have used user assemblies (**java binding library for Pull to Refresh component**) and   **Newtonsoft.Json**  from Nuget Packages . These assemblies are referenced in our android project.

It is **working fine with Debug mode**, when we change to **Release mode it shows the error** as You need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll when you use ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute..

we have referenced the Mono.Android.Export.dll but shows error in release mode alone.

**Note:**

I have done the following in Android Project Properties for Release build

Mono Android Options -> Configuration -> Release 
                                    Linking -> Sdk and User Assemblies 
                                    Bundle assemblies into native code enabled.

Kindly find the attached image for your reference and help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark some classes witch [Export] Attribute. Probably c# classes which represents json objects.

When linking your assemblies, these classes/methods could considered as not used by the linker and not included in final linked code.